# How to animate a View to hide underneath another view, and then animate from that View

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, android-gridview

I have two grid views that I would like to create a custom animation for. 
Imagine this layout:

```
___________________________________________
|                                         |
|                                         |
|               TOP Grid                  |
|                                         |
|_________________________________________|
|                                         |
|                                         |
|                 BOTTOM                  |
|                 Grid                    |
|                                         |
|_________________________________________|
```

The bottom grid will 'slide out' and 'slide' behind the top grid.  I figure I should be using a translate animation.  How do I find out the fromX & fromY values?   I thought I could have both View in a Layout, and then set the animation as RelativeToParent.

It this the right approach?  If you know of anywhere I can find source code for this functionality I would greatly appreciate it.  Thank you,

Comment: do you have any solution to do this? I also try to find out. Currently the Bottom grid will cover top grid when animation. And they are in LinearLayout

Answer (score 0):

Try out this `slide-out` & `slide-in` Animations.

`slide-top-in.xml`

> ```
>  <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
>    <translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
>     android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
>     android:fromYDelta="0" 
>     android:toYDelta="-100%p" 
>     android:duration="1000" 
>                />
>   </set>
> ```

`slide-top-out.xml`

> ```
> <translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
>     android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
>     android:fromYDelta="-100%p"
>     android:toYDelta="0"
>     android:duration="1000" />
> ```